# perl - extract only from function definitions and not from function declarations

Tags: regex, perl

FILE CONTAINS FUNCTION DEFINITIONS AND FUNCTION DECLARATIONS

```
eErrorT ChainCtrlUpdateCameraRoute(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pNewRoute, RouteListItemT* pCurrRoute);

eErrorT ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pRoute, char * dst_chain, char *jpg_file_path)
{

}
```

MY CODE

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw(@temp $index $i);

open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;
my @arr = <$FILE>;
foreach(@arr){  
   if($_ =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {    # extracts function arguments
      my $arg = $1;
      my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
      print @temp = map "$_\n", @arr;
     }
}
```

GIVES OUTPUT

```
pChainCtrl
pNewRoute
pCurrRoute
pChainCtrl
pRoute
dst_chain
jpg_file_path
```

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
pChainCtrl
pRoute
dst_chain
jpg_file_path
```

I need to extract arguments only from function definition(ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile) and not declaration(ChainCtrlUpdateCameraRoute).

I need to look whether the line with (..) doesn't have ";" in the same line. but I am unable to get regex command for it

Comment: `//` is not a comment in Perl, use `#` for that. `//` is the "defined-or" operator.

Comment: it was just to explain the code..actual code is quite bigger than this.I just gave u a sample where I am stuck

Comment: Why don't you just add a semi-colon in a negative lookahead assertion? `(?!\s*;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand what is the technical (lexical) difference, I see a ";" at the end of the definition, and no no ";" at the end of the declaration. In addition you have a { at the next line.

Utilizing these features (if they are consitent, fingers x'ed)

```
#ignore lines with ; (followed by optional spaces) at the end
print @temp = map "$_\n", @arr 
    unless $_ =~ /;\s*$/;
```

An option may be look for the { at the next line, and only print previous line, if you had a match, and this line start with a {. (to be left as an exercise...)